# Using ObservableCollection in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, observablecollection

I need to use functionality that **[`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)** provides, in my asp.net app. My only concern is that this class is a part of WindowsBase assembly and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to include a windows assembly in a web project.

Any ideas/comments?

Thanks!

Comment: The namespace this class lives in is `Systems.Collection.ObjectModel`. I suspect the programmers of the class intended it to have *broad* usage.

Comment: Robert: Yes, it lives in Systems.Collection.ObjectModel namespace, but it requires windows core assembly to be referenced and I'm just not sure it's a kosher thing to do

Comment: Fredrik: I intend to use it in my middle tier - I have collections of users, templates etc, and now every time I need, say to add a user on the UI, I add one via a middle tier method and then have to make sure that my collection is up to date as well. 
If I were to use ObservableCollection, I would just have to add a user to the collection, and the event that is triggered on the collection, would update the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a creative use for `ObservableCollection` outside of WPF, I don't see any reason you should not take advantage of it.  Even [Microsoft says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):

> Before implementing your own
>   collection, consider using
>   `ObservableCollection<T>` or one of
>   the existing collection classes, such
>   as `List<T>`, `Collection<T>`, and
>   `BindingList<T>`, among many others.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx) has an example of an `ObservableCollection` in WPF.  However, the author makes this statement at the end of the article:

> Although this application made use of
>   the binding support provided by the
>   ObservableCollection class and also
>   reacted to its CollectionChanged event
>   in order to update the user interface,
>   *you needn't use the class this way.* Because it notifies listeners that its
>   contents have changed, you can replace
>   **any** List or Collection instance that
>   you use with an ObservableCollection
>   instance (*even if you're not creating
>   a WPF application*) and then hook up
>   event handlers to notify clients that
>   the collection's contents have
>   changed.

Comment: Robert, I explained why I was concerned about using ObservableCollection within my asp.net app - it's housed in the windows assembly.

Comment: @Andrey:You have nothing to worry about. The assembly is just a collection of classes.  See my edit.

Comment: Cannot use in ASP.NET Core tho I guess, and I would avoid for this reason, not future proof... Are you developing a WebForms or MVC app? I guess the CollectionChanged event could also be used with SignalR?